# Storing variables in mysql in for loops

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project where I need to save some variables to a database and retrieve some of those variables in a class to recalculate the next batch of variables.

However I came to realise that the current project is running too slow and find out where the leak was: in storing those variables. (Insert statement in PHP)

Since the insert statement can get in a pretty big for loop, like this ($auctionobjects and numberofdays is filled in by the user, $hours == 24):

```
for($i = 0; $i< $numberofdays)  {
    for ($n = 0; $n < $hours)  {
        for ($k = 0; $k < $auctionobjects)  {
        $strSql = 'insert into results (vars) values ()'
        $blnOke = $objDatabase->query($strSql)
        }
    }
 }
```

The waiting time can get pretty long, which is not desirable as the simulation must be able to run for a pretty long time.

Now my idea was to get an insert statement as the following:

```
$strSql = 'insert into results (vars) values (), (),()'
```

But the variables that fill the columns in MySql change troughout the simulation. Since I don't know how big the $auctionobjects variable will be, I cannot get the right number of brackets I need to fill in.

What I could do is create a variable that creates the string needed for the amount of $auctionobjects like this:

```
$createSqlString  = '(vars)'
for($x = 0; $x< $auctionobjects; $x ++)  {
   $createSqlString .= ,(vars)
}
```

And then insert it in the Sql statement, but I am not sure if there is a more clean solution.

Comment: If `(vars)` in the last example are the actual values you want to insert, that seems like a pretty reasonable solution. Maybe start a new query after 100 values or so.

Comment: Yes they are, thanks for replying :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
$createSqlString = `INSERT INTO results (var, var, var) VALUES ';
$vars = array();

for($x = 0; $x < $auctionobjects; $x ++)  {
    /* processing ... */
    $vars[] = "($val1, $val2, $val3)";
}
$createSqlString .= implode (',', $vars);
```

`implode` is pretty nice for these SQL-style comma separated lists.

If you wanted to be really careful about bind variables to prevent injection attacks, you could try this:

```
$createSqlString = `INSERT INTO results (var, var, var) VALUES ()';
$sqls = array();
$vals = array();

for($x = 0; $x < $auctionobjects; $x ++)  {
    /* processing ... */
    $sqls[] = '(?,?,?)';
    $vals[] = $val1;
    $vals[] = $val2;
    $vals[] = $val2;
}
$createSqlString .= implode (',', $vars);
/* then bind the $vals array to the statement and execute it */
```

Comment: Think you misunderstood my question, but you are underlining the idea I had, so I am accepting your answer :).